# Preprint of Hamilton on deformations of foliations

Tags: reference-request, foliations, dg.differential-geometry

Does anyone have access to Hamilton's 1978 Cornell preprint 'Deformation Theory of Foliations'. It is widely quoted but I couldn't find any online copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a printed copy, but I don't think it was ever published or put online. If you contact me, I can make a copy and send it to you.

Comment: Perhaps, with the permission of the author, this could be scanned and put on arxiv?

Comment: @Igor: As far as I know, arXiv rejects scanned files (at least it was so a while ago).